# figuring out the way to pass header in PHP

Tags: php, header

Referring to the following PHP code [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/)

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'foo foo foo',
    'bar' => 'bar bar bar',
    'baz' => 'baz baz baz'
);
```

The explanation for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` below the code in the document says that :

equivilent HTML form value for this might be something like `<input type='hidden' name='foo' value='foo foo foo' />`

1)How did the person who explained the code in the document figured out that the type was `hidden` in its HTML equivalent?

2)What if I have to use `type = header`, then how would the PHP code would look like?

Comment: You should post the relevant code here.

Comment: 1) The author made an example, he didn't figure anything out (either way, `view source` is available in any browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out form elements of a remote page by downloading it and parsing it using an HTML parser like this : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or you could simple view source and forge your script accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to figure out if I have to send a header field, does there need to be an additional field in addition to `'foo' => 'foo foo foo',` ? I believe since the type is hidden for all the array values right now, there is no need to add any thing in `'foo' => 'foo foo foo'`.

Comment: When using php curl, you send headers differently and post data differently. 



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Header#1: value1', 'Header#2: value2'));


Form data (get/post data) is sent differently:



$data = array('foo' => 'foo foo foo', 'bar' => 'bar bar bar', 'baz' => 'baz baz baz' );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);


The type="hidden" attribute is HTML markup telling the browser to hide that input field from showing. Internally, all the form data is sent equally.

You should look up how an HTTP GET/POST request looks like internally for understanding.